# Bad Access in C Bubblesort for same functions using Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, bubble-sort

I'm learning C using Xcode so I've been practicing the bubble sort algorithm.
You can see my code (failing) here as bubbleSort1 function and bubbleSort2 passing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b= temp;
}

void bubbleSort1(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)


        for (j = 0; i < n-i-1; j++)
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}

void bubbleSort2(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)

        // Last i elements are already in place
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size){
    printf("Array:\t");
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");
}

int main(){

    int array2[8] = {9, 15, 7, 4, 1, 11, 3, 4};
    int length2 = sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0]);
    printArray(array2,length2);
    bubbleSort2(array2,length2);
    printArray(array2, length2);

    int array1[8] = {9, 15, 7, 4, 1, 11, 3, 4};
    int length1 = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);
    printArray(array1,length1);
    bubbleSort1(array1,length1);
    printArray(array1, length1);

    return 0;
}
```

From the code you can see that bubbleSort1 and bubbleSort2 are almost the same, except by the commented line.

However I have some strange "Bad Access" error when running my code, and the XCode debugger kept telling me that j in bubblesort1 is 667, and an error in line 24. You can see an snapshot here:

[image: As you can see bubbleSort1 and bubbleSort2 are similar]

In the image you can see that bubbleSort2 runs without problems, despite being the same as bubbleSort1.

The same error happens when run  each function by itself.

Is this an Xcode error? Or am I missing something, considering I'm just beginning to learn C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bubbleSort1` has an incorrect for loop.

`for (j = 0; i < n-i-1; j++)` should be `for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)`

Comment: I guess I should start using an alternative to i and j since I can seem to distinguish them in code

Comment: `i` and `j` are pretty common for things like this and will popup all over the place in other people's code. Perhaps try a different font (or bigger size) to help you distinguish them

Answer (score 1):

Change this function as below

```
void bubbleSort1(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) // it's j not i
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array:  9 15 7 4 1 11 3 4 

Array:  1 3 4 4 7 9 11 15 

Array:  9 15 7 4 1 11 3 4 

Array:  1 3 4 4 7 9 11 15
```

Comment: It's not end of the world, some time happens, Keep coding.. :)